# Draw a table in vertical display instead of horizontal display

Tags: latex

Can Someone tell me by which command I can draw a table in vertical display in LaTex.

Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean by vertical display? It is not clear enough.

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Horizontal mean in a page rows eill be from left to right and columns will be from up to down.. Now I want to rotate this table by 90 degree. Mean rows should be from bottom to up and columns should be from left to right... Now is this clear?

Comment: Now I understand that you are trying to do something with the whole table rather than with each cell, nor trying to escape from tex vertical mode. What you are saying is quite complicated. Horizontal: rotate the whole table clockwise 90 degrees, then filp it vertically, Vertically: rotate the whole table 180 degrees, then flip it horizontally?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you want the `lscape` package, can be usefully used for this purpose as follows:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{....}
.......
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

---

EDIT 2nd solution:
Another possibility is to use the `sideways` environment from the `rotating` package:

```
\begin{sideways}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{sideways}
```

And for floating tables `sidewaystable`.

Comment: It is giving me the error as `LaTeX error: Environment landscape undefined`... Any suggestions..?

Comment: @anilonwebs, you probably need `\usepackage{lscape}` in the preamble.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a package use `usepackage` :)

Comment: It is working fine but is table resides in the left side of the page and right side of page shows empty one. Is there any option to keeping this table in center of the page. I found that using `sidewaystable` we can do it but that is also not working.. :(

Comment: Great! but can you tell me how to change the way of `sideways` from left to right?

Comment: @lonesome I'm not using that package since long time. Please check out the official documentation.

Comment: I find this useful as an example of `sidewaystable` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46005/inserting-table-and-figure-vertically-in-a-full-page?newreg=aca472173e804a1ca55e2c59e8fc3c1f

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me to display the table at the center of vertical position.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Table name}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
A & B & C \\
20  &23 &56 \\
25  &25 &65 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```